# How can I reduce the amount of text in my HTML code

Tags: html, code-readability

I'm currently trying to write a page with 1000+ words (examples include news articles, reports, and blog posts)

the problem is if I put more than 75 words between a pair of `<p>` tags not only does the file become ugly and unreadable it's also terribly inefficient.

so how do you clean it up in a way that those 1000+ words can still be interacted with and formatted as if they were jammed into the middle of the document?

what is the standard solution to this problem?
is there a way to use substitution?
or is it better to read from a file?

Answer (score 0):

Download a good editor, such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). One native feature is block folding, as shown in the following gif. I have thousands of lines of HTML which condense down to one block spanning only two lines.

[image]